# No duplication of e-mail during registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In order not to duplicate the email and username in the database, instead of the **any** command in SQL, I used **is unique** in the index section. Now, if a duplicate is entered, it throws an InnerException error. Now, how do I display this error to the user for both the email and the username?

`

```
 public bool IsExistUserName(string userName)
    {
        return _context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == userName);
    }

    public bool IsExistEmail(string email)
    {
        return _context.Users.Any(u => u.Email == email);
    }
```

`//`

```
 public IActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel register)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(register);
        }

        if (_userService.IsExistUserName(register.UserName))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "You have already registered with this username");
            return View(register);
        }

        if (_userService.IsExistEmail(register.Email.Trim().ToLower()))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "You have already registered with this email");
            return View(register);
        }
        User user = new User
        {
            UserName = register.UserName,
            Email = register.Email.Trim().ToLower(),
            Password = HashPassword.EncodePasswordMd5(register.Password),
            ActiveCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", ""),
            IsActive = false,
            RegisterDate = DateTime.Now,

        };
        _userService.AddUser(user);
        return View("SuccsesRegister", user);
    }
```

`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLV73.png)

In this code, **any** is used, but I don't want to use **any**, I want to use the feature(is unique) shown in the above photo and display the error it gives to the user for both email and username.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UugPs.png)

```
  public  IActionResult Create([Bind("Name,InsertDateTime,Id,Code")] ActivityType activityType)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _typeBaseService.AddActivityType(activityType);

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "This name is duplicated");
            ModelState.AddModelError("Code", "This code is duplicated");

        }
       
          

        return View(activityType);
    }
```

Comment: Did you look at the exception it causes to find the corresponding error code, etc?

Comment: This code does not give an error, I do not want to use the method of this code

Comment: You should first check the `inner exception` if that contains `Unique_constraint_name` exception then you can bind your `ModelState.AddModelError` what you want to display to user.

Comment: Please write the code for me

Comment: Share your relevant code where you are getting error `it throws an InnerException error.`

Comment: I posted his photo

Comment: what is IX_ActivityTypes constraint in the table?

Comment: Photo is not relevant here, if you expect exact code, you must need to share your exact code.

Comment: In order not to enter a duplicate record

Comment: I put my code, but my code is wrong

Comment: Please try the solution, and let me know if you encounter further issue.

Comment: Often exceptions provide additional information that's unique to their type. This information can be very useful sometimes. For example, your [Sql Exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.errors?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-errors) has a collection of `SqlError` objects in the `Errors` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify you could as below:

**Controller:**

```
public  IActionResult Create([Bind("Name,InsertDateTime,Id,Code")] ActivityType activityType)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _typeBaseService.AddActivityType(activityType);

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
            {

                Exception innerException = ex;
                while (innerException.InnerException != null)
                {
                    innerException = innerException.InnerException;
                }

                if (innerException.Message.Contains("Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint"))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Same Name or Email found!");
                    return View("Index");
                }

               
            }
       
          

        return View(activityType);
    }
```

**Note:** Please check your `inner exception` and message in my case upon `duplicate name` I am getting `Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint"` message, make sure what you got there and set that message on `innerException.Message.Contains("Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint")`. So it will be traced accordingly. Please see screenshot below:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]